# parsing json fields in React

Tags: reactjs, json

I store property details pulled from a REST API in a jsonb field in Postgresql and when querying it from the DB, I get the following structure

```
{
   "mls":{
      "id":"14648351",
      "name":"NTREIS",
      "type":"mls",
      "plan_id":null,
      "abbreviation":"NTTX"
   },
   "beds":4,
   "rank":1,
   "baths":4,
   "price":822825,
   "agents":[
      {
         "name":"*** ***",
         "photo":null,
         "primary":true
      }
   ],
   "office":{
      "id":"b96d60e549a4ed49a54a4c20920dd94e",
      "name":"5Th Stream Realty"
   },
 "prop_type":"single_family",
   "thumbnail":"https://ap.rdcpix.com/3b2641a18da2d9af689a3cf1146e5495l-m4140099391x.jpg",
   "baths_full":3,
   "baths_half":1,
   .....
```

I need to pull out the fields from the above JSON and display them on the webpage. I am using React. I have the following code.

```
const HouseCard = ({ house }) => (
    <div>{house.property} </div>
);

HouseCard.propTypes = {
  house: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

I am getting house.property is the JSON data. I want to pull out the individual fields and display them in the house card.

I am trying to get a sample of how to pull the individual keys and the values from the JSON params to display.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to convert it to a JS object using `JSON.parse()`

Like this:

```
const HouseCard = ({ house }) => (
const houseData = JSON.parse(house)

};
```

Now you can use the data in the component. I am not sure what data you want to display where but if you want to get all the keys of the object you can use `const keys = Object.keys(house)`

This will return an array with all the keys in the object then you can dynamically iterate over them:

```
{keys.map(key=> <div> houseData[key] </div>)}
```

You'll have to check if it's an array inside that property too if you want to display also the objects in those arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the keys in the object like this:

```
const HouseCard = ({ house }) => (
    <div>
        {Object.keys(house.property).map((key) => 
            (<p> { house.property[key] } </p>)
        )}
    </div>
);
```